# Restore original permissions for system files

Tags: permissions

I have a machine which all its system drive files e.g `/etc/*` `/lib/*` `/home/*` where moved to a storage system by mistake. Now I moved them back to their original places but I don't know how to set the permissions to the original one?

Comment: There is no feasible way. You'll have to reinstall.

Comment: I did it once too, so loaded another box with the same setup (may have been a restore from an older backup) and wrote a script to clone the permissions from the 'alternate' machine to the one I wanted to fix.  It was a huge amount of [messy] work .. and re-install would be far quicker (*and less heart-ache*)..